# Fixing a broken pipe underground without breaking the floor

Tags: plumbing, pipe, plumbing-fixture

Is there any way to fix a broken pipe that's located underground?
I was thinking of something like a camera and a liquid like the ones used with broken wheels...
And I'll try soon.

Has anyone successfully fixed one without destroying the floor?

(it's the drain pipe from the sink).

Answer (score 3):

The answer to your question is "yes" - but it's a specialist job.  For example http://insitudrain.co.uk/commercial-industrial-services/cure-lining/ can remotely apply a liner and then cure it. (I found them by searching for "in-situ drain repair".

If you are contemplating a DIY approach, it's probably easier to dig down, repair, and make good.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not something that can be tackled as a DIY job. There are a variety of techniques that can achieve this, but they all require very expensive tools, and some minor excavation in some instances. Popular methods are pipe bursting (a hydraulic tool is pulled through the existing pipe and removes it by breaking it up, then a new pipe is pulled in its place) and cured in place pipe (a liner is pulled through the existing pipe and then cured with heat). However, both these methods are most often used for applications in the sewer main or sewer service line, which are generally at least 4" in diameter or larger. Your kitchen sink pipe is highly unlikely to be that large, so there probably won't be any tools available in the right size even for contractors do use the above-mentioned techniques.

Maybe you could find some sort of flexible pipe that you could pull through the existing one, but then that won't be one typically used for wastewater, so you will not be able to find any fittings to connector at each end. You would also need to reduce the size from the existing, so the new pipe fits the one that's there, which may be an issue depending on the existing size.

Comment: Thanks PhilippNagel's, from the DIY prospective, the pipe inside the pipe seems brilliant! Let's try it